# How to allow services to make real http calls on Angular 5 tests

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

In my Angular 5 app I've got some smoke tests or sanity checks that I want some of the services to make real http calls in order to assure the downstream dependencies endpoints are still valid / accessible.
I've already tried to import the real HttpModule in the TestBed as well as inject the real implementantions but it looks like the http call is not going through. Also I've been digging on the documentation but I couldn't find any conclusive ideas.
Does anyone know a way to make it work?

My current test spec is like the below:

```
describe('My Smoke Test', () => {
    beforeEach(async (done) => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: Router, useValue: router },
            HttpRequestService,
            AppConfigService,
            ServerRoutingService,
            ProductService,
            {
                provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                useFactory: appInitializerFn,
                multi: true,
                deps: [AppConfigService]
            }
        ],
        imports: [
            HttpModule
        ]
    })
    ...
   })

   it('Checking products endpoint', () => { 
      let productService = TestBed(ProductService)
      productService.getFirst().subscribe(
          response => expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200),
      )
   })
})
```

I also tried async, fakeAsync as the productService.getFirst() method returns an Observable so maybe the promise is not being executed?

Comment: Should not this be done inside e2e test? I wonder

Comment: That's what I thought despite I really just wanted to make sure that once I deploy the app the downstream dependencies are reachable, now I think the e2e would ne the best option.